# Spring gateway add cookies on response header without sending to proxied service

Tags: java, spring

We have a gateway service in front of some microservices.

On the gateway we have a secrity filter which is handling every request before routing it the resource-service by sending the request to a security-service which authorize the request. Basically we have some cookies with access token and refresh token which are send to security-service.

Also on the security-service we are checking the access token and refresh token and if the access token expired then a new one is generated.

The problem is, when a new access token was generated we have to send it back to browser in order to replace the expired one.

So my question is, can be implemented the following flow on spring gateway?

1. Intercept the request by SecurityGatewayFilter
2. Security servce authorize the request and also generate a new access token which is send back via cookies to gateway.
3. Keep the new access token on filters chain
4. Routing to resource-service
5. On some post gateway filter add on the response the new access token and let the browser the replace the expired one.